Sort the cols/rows of a 2D array of numbers using minimal swaps
Given a random array of 25 unique numbers in 5x5 2D array such as:
[
[2, 95, 86, 53, 38],
[32, 50, 37, 73, 98],
[49, 69, 35, 23, 97],
[96, 44, 65, 10, 17],
[39, 45, 67, 36, 99]
]
What is the best algorithm or heuristic to minimize the number of swaps so that each row is sorted left > right and each column is sorted top > bottom?
Note: You can swap ANY two elements on the board. (Do not need to be adjacent)
Note: The 5 smallest numbers do NOT have to be in the top row.
Note: The 5 biggest numbers do NOT have to be in the bottom row.
Note: It only matters that EACH row and EACH column is sorted.
Note: It should be clear that there is more than one possible solutions.

I don't know what might work and I don't have a good solution.  One possible approach is to use A* search, with some appropriately chosen heuristic.  I am not sure what would be a good heuristic.  One option is to use $(1/16) \sum_v n(v)$ where $v$ ranges over all rows and columns and $n(v)$ counts the number of inversions in a 1D array of length 5.
Without loss of generality, we can assume that the input numbers are 1,2,..,25 (by relabelling and replacing each number with its rank/position in a sorted list of all input numbers).

Random tidbit: Your problem is related to the Lucky Numbers board game (see also here).  When playing this game, a rough rule of thumb I have found useful is to try to fill in the diagonal (from top left to bottom right) first.  That might be a basis for a candidate heuristic algorithm.
The 1D version of this problem is solved here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/15152322/781723

That is an interesting approach, do you mean the top/left to bot/right diagonal or the top/right to bot/left diagonal?
We've been trying a "legal position" heuristic. For example: the 2nd highest number must be next to the highest number (98 vs 99 in the above) meaning the 4th position of row 5 or the 5th position of row 4. The inverse is true for the 2nd lowest number. The 3rd highest/lowest is now similarly constrained. The middle numbers must trend towards the top/right and bot/left diagonal.
It is a hard algorithm to search for but was curious if it was solved. Thanks!

@RoscoSchock, top left to bottom right diagonal.  Makes sense.
